# Can Zorn's Lemma be 'inverted' like this:?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a (commutative) ring not equal to $0$. I want to show that the set of prime ideals of $R$ has a ***minimal*** element w.r.t. inclusion.

This may be a wholeheartedly wrong attempt, but I thought I'd try this:

Let $P$ be the set of all prime ideals of $R$. We have chains of prime ideals with respect to inclusion, i.e.

$\mathfrak{p}_1\supset \mathfrak{p}_2\supset\ldots\supset \mathfrak{p}_n\supset\ldots $

Now consider the chain $R/\mathfrak{p}_1\subset R/\mathfrak{p}_2\subset\ldots\subset R$.

This has a maximal element, namely $R$, so if we let $U$ be the set $\{R/\mathfrak{p}_i : \mathfrak{p}_i\: \text{is prime}\}$, then every chain has a maximal element, so if we take the order-reversing chains, there must be a minimal element for each chain, hence $P$ has a minimal element w.r.t. inclusion.

I suspect this may be pretty dodgy logic, but I think I don't have a full understanding of when best to apply the lemma.

Comment: $\{0\}$ seems to be the smallest imaginable ideal for any ring $R$.

Comment: But in a ring that isn't an integral domain $\{0\}$ is not a prime ideal!

Comment: @Ramified: $R/I$ is never a subset of $R/J$ for any ideals $I\neq J$. Moreover, if $\{0\}$ is **not** a prime ideal, then $R$ isn't in $U$, so it makes no sense to say that $R$ is an upper bound for some chain in $U$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Ah. That may hinder the argument somewhat..

Comment: True again. Shall I delete the question? Turns out I hadn't thought it through very much.

Comment: @Ramified: No, in fact it's a good question: you can apply Zorn's lemma here, though your argument needs some correction. Noah's answer below is good.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Zev, just a brief question about your earlier point: Do we not have that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ as a set? I know this isn't in keeping with my question as $4\mathbb{Z}$ is not prime, but surely this is a counterexample to what you claimed..

Comment: @Ramified_Minds: No, that is incorrect. The elements of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ are the cosets
$$\begin{align*}
0+2\mathbb{Z}&=\{\ldots,-4,-2,0,2,4,\ldots\}\\
1+2\mathbb{Z}&=\{\ldots,-3,-1,1,3,5\ldots\}
\end{align*}$$
The elements of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ are the cosets
$$\begin{align*}
0+4\mathbb{Z}&=\{\ldots,-8,-4,0,4,8,\ldots\}\\
1+4\mathbb{Z}&=\{\ldots,-7,-3,1,5,9,\ldots\}\\
2+4\mathbb{Z}&=\{\ldots,-6,-2,2,6,10,\ldots\}\\
3+4\mathbb{Z}&=\{\ldots,-5,-1,3,7,11,\ldots\}
\end{align*}$$
None of the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ are elements of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and vice versa

Comment: Ok I agree. I guess I was thinking just about the coset reps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three questions here.

The first question is whether your argument works. The answer is, not yet: see Zev Chonoles' comment.

---

Second, whether you can apply Zorn's lemma "upside-down." The answer is yes: if $P$ is a poset, then its "inversion" (just reverse the ordering) $P^*$ is a poset, and if $P^*$ satisfies the hypotheses of Zorn then $P^*$ has a maximal element, hence $P$ has a minimal element.

Unwinding this, we get: if every descending chain in $P$ has a lower bound, then $P$ has a minimal element.

---

So third question is, what's the gap? Well, the object you've defined isn't really the "inverse" of the poset of prime ideals - I think you're trying to hard. You can just order the prime ideals by reverse inclusion, which I think is what is going on intuitively with your definition. Then everything works the way it should.

Comment: Thanks for the clear response. What actually *is* the inverse of a poset then? Is it just the same set with the ordering going the other way?

Comment: Yup! This is one time when thinking too hard about it actually obscures the right approach. Just flip it around!

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks: You consider only a *specific* chain that happens to end in $R$. Admittedly, this shows that $R$ is an upper bound for *any* chain. But doesn't that make the application of Zorn useless - after all you start with a very maximal element! On the other hand, it may happen that $R=R/0$ is not even a valid maximum because it is not the quotient by a prime ideal (if $R$ has zero-divisors).

That being said, no one prevents you from defining the order on the set of prime ideals as $\mathfrak p\le\mathfrak q:\iff \mathfrak q\subseteq \mathfrak p$. This way a "maximal" prime ideal is one that is inclusion-minimal. However, you still have to show that Zorn *applies*. That is: Given a chain of prime ideals (a set $\{\,\mathfrak p_i\mid i\in I\,\}$ such that for $i, j\in I$ we have $\mathfrak p_i\le \mathfrak p_j$ or $\mathfrak p_j\le \mathfrak p_i$), does there exist an "upper" bound for the chain (i.e., is there a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ with $\mathfrak p_i\le \mathfrak p$ for all $i\in I$)? Under the partial order ${\le}:={\supseteq}$, something like $\bigcap _{i\in I}\mathfrak p_i$ would seem to be a natural *candidate* for an upper bound - but is it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My very first instinct was to think about that intersection , but then I changed track because I didn't know how to use Zorn's Lemma with it. I think that fits the bill, since it is a prime ideal, and we have the chain $\mathfrak{p}_1\supseteq \mathfrak{p}_1\cap\mathfrak{p}_2\supseteq\mathfrak{p}_1\cap\mathfrak{p}_2\cap \mathfrak{p}_3$ etc.